# Set Console output to specific row

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have a console app that I'm working on that outputs realtime event-related information using Console.WriteLine (on a separate thread).  The app also allows the user to enter commands via Console.ReadLine().  When output occurs at the same time that the user is entering a command, the output gets intermixed with the input.  As a result, I'm looking for a way to keep the bottom row of the console window reserved for input while setting the output to appear on the next to last row (and scroll up from there), thereby avoiding the intermixing.

Any advice on how to get this to work would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How is this possible unless you have `ReadLine()` and `WriteLine()` Collision going on can you show what code you are using currently..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Console.SetCursorPosition and then Console.Write

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx

But you can't use Console.ReadLine, try something with [Console.ReadKey(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx) and then write entered keys in last line. In fact you have to simulate Console.ReadLine with ReadKey and Write.

Comment: Good thinking, but that would also interfere with the simultaneous input I'm afraid.